# Coordinates with respect to basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $$v _1 = (1, 1), v _2 = (1, 3)$$  Let $x$ and $y$ be the coordinates with respect to the standard basis: $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ and let $u$ and $v$ be the coordinates with respect to $v_1, v_2$.  Write the equations to translate from $(x, y)$ to $(u, v)$ and back.  I have the equations by solving the system

\begin{array}{rcl} u+v=x \\ u+3v=y\end{array}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your system you have:
$$
\begin{cases}
u=\frac{3}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}y\\
v=-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}y
\end{cases}
$$
so the matrices that represent the change of basis are:
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
1&3
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad 
M^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{3}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\\
-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$